# self written Node class for link list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am taking a Java course and part of our homework is to write single link list class and class for Node.

this class contain two members:\

```
private BusArrival _busArr;
private BusArrivalNode _next;
```

where BusArrival is a previously written class and works as it should.

I'm having trouble with **setNext** method, specially how to copy the data of **next node** and not the pointer

This is the class I wrote:
as said all the method of BusArrival class works fine

```
public class BusArrivalNode 
{
    private BusArrival _busArr;
    private BusArrivalNode _next;


    public BusArrivalNode (BusArrival b) 
    {
        _busArr = new BusArrival(b);
        _next = null;
    }


    public BusArrivalNode (BusArrival b, BusArrivalNode n)
    {
        _busArr = new BusArrival(b);
        _next = n;
    }

    public BusArrivalNode ( BusArrivalNode n)
    {
         _busArr = new BusArrival(n._busArr);
     _next = n._next;

    }

    public BusArrival getBusArr()
    {
        return _busArr;
    }

    public BusArrivalNode getNext()
    {
        return _next;
    }


    public void setBussArr(BusArrival b)
    {
        _busArr.setArrivalTime(b.getArrivalTime());
        _busArr.setLineNum(b.getLineNum());
        _busArr.setNoOfPass(b.getNoOfPass());

    }


    public void setNext(BusArrivalNode next) ** IS THIS THE  CORRECT WAY?**
    {
        _next._busArr = new BusArrival(next._busArr);
        _next._next = new BusArrivalNode(next._next);
    }
}
```

Comment: "i'm having trouble" isn't detailed enough. also you should have some kind of test harness. it's unclear what the problem is, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. also learn about junit.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you appear to be having issues with, `BusArrivalNode(BusArrivalNode n)`, it creates a new `BusArrivalNode` named `tmp` that has the same `_busArr` and `_next` members as the node that is given.

You then set the current class's `_next._busArr` to a value. When you do that, `_next`  hasn't been defined yet, so you're setting member of a null value. This is going to cause a NullPointerException because you're trying to do something to nothing.

The current contents of that constructor:

```
BusArrivalNode tmp = new BusArrivalNode(n._busArr, n._next);
_next._busArr = tmp._busArr;
_next._busArr = tmp._busArr;
```

What you likely want:

```
_busArr = n._busArr;
_next = n._next;
```

Comment: thank you. I made a little different change 
can it work also?

Comment: It may or may not work, depending on what you want it to do. If you want `_busArr` to point to a new `BusArrival` that has the same value as the passed in node's `_busArr`, then yes, your new code is probably correct. You need to provide more information about the assignment for better help.

Answer (score 0):

**thank you , got the mistake. 
copy ctor works on not yet created objects, ones got it made some corrections
and this is the Node class that work in my case:**

```
public class BusArrivalNode 
{
    private BusArrival _busArr;
    private BusArrivalNode _next;


    public BusArrivalNode (BusArrival b)
    {
        _busArr = new BusArrival(b);
        _next = null;
    }


    public BusArrivalNode (BusArrival b, BusArrivalNode n)
    {
        _busArr = new BusArrival(b);
        _next = n;
    }


    public BusArrivalNode ( BusArrivalNode n)
    {
         _busArr = new BusArrival(n._busArr);
         _next = n._next;   
    }


    public BusArrival getBusArr()
    {
        return _busArr;
    }


    public BusArrivalNode getNext()
    {
        return _next;
    }


    public void setBussArr(BusArrival b)
    {
        _busArr.setArrivalTime(b.getArrivalTime());
        _busArr.setLineNum(b.getLineNum());
        _busArr.setNoOfPass(b.getNoOfPass());

    }


    public void setNext(BusArrivalNode next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
}
```